# How to iterate and loop through this XML response with cUrl and PHP?

Tags: php, xml, curl

I need help looping through a complex XML response I receive from making an api call using PHP cURL. I think I've tried everything I could find here on SO and in the PHP [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/simplexmlelement.attributes.php). Nothing works. I need help understanding how to do this. For instance if I wanted to print the admin address, how would I do this?

**PHP cURL**

```
$ch = curl_init($connection_details['api_host_port']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
//
//
//
//parse xml string into SimpleXML objects
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
print_r($xml);
```

**Full Response**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[header] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[version] => 0.9
)

[body] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[data_block] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[dt_assoc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[item] => Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => attributes
)

[dt_assoc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[item] => Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => affiliate_id
)

)

[1] => 1
[2] => 2020-08-24 21:55:12
[3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => nameserver_list
)

[dt_array] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[item] => Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => 0
)

[dt_assoc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[item] => Array
(
[0] => ns1.systemdns.com
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => ipaddress
)

)

[2] => 1
)

)

)

[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => 1
)

[dt_assoc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[item] => Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => ipaddress
)

)

[1] => 2
[2] => ns2.systemdns.com
)

)

)

)

)

)

[4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => tld_data
)

)

[5] => 2021-08-24 21:55:10
[6] => NONE
[7] => 2021-08-24 21:55:10
[8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => contact_set
)

[dt_assoc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[item] => Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => owner
)

[dt_assoc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[item] => Array
(
[0] => +1.5556667777
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => address2
)

)

[2] => Miami
[3] => John
[4] => NA
[5] => FL
[6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => address3
)

)

[7] => active
[8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => fax
)

)

[9] => 3200 Northwest 67th Avenue
[10] => Doe
[11] => tech@example.com
[12] => US
[13] => 33122
)

)

)

[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => admin
)

[dt_assoc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[item] => Array
(
[0] => Miami
[1] => John
[2] => FL
[3] => NA
[4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => address3
)

)

[5] => active
[6] => 3200 Northwest 67th Avenue
[7] => Doe
[8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => fax
)

)

[9] => tech@example.com
[10] => US
[11] => 33122
[12] => +1.5556667777
[13] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => address2
)

)

)

)

)

[2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => billing
)

[dt_assoc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[item] => Array
(
[0] => +1.5556667777
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => address2
)

)

[2] => FL
[3] => NA
[4] => Miami
[5] => John
[6] => tech@example.com
[7] => 33122
[8] => US
[9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => address3
)

)

[10] => 3200 Northwest 67th Avenue
[11] => active
[12] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => fax
)

)

[13] => Doe
)

)

)

[3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => tech
)

[dt_assoc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[item] => Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => address2
)

)

[1] => +1.5556667777
[2] => Jane Doe
[3] => Los Angeles
[4] => CA
[5] => Company Name
[6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => fax
)

)

[7] => active
[8] => 555 My Street
[9] => Jane Doe
[10] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[key] => address3
)

)

[11] => US
[12] => 77788
[13] => tech@example.com
)

)

)

)

)

)

[9] => 1
[10] => 2020-08-24 21:55:10
[11] => 0
)

)

)

[1] => DOMAIN
[2] => 200
[3] => XCP
[4] => REPLY
[5] => Query Successful
[6] => 1
)

)

)

)

)
```

**per request EDIT WITH $xml->asXML():**

```
  0.9
  

 
  
   
    Query Successful
    200
    1
    XCP
    DOMAIN
    REPLY
    
     
      1
      
      
       
        
         
          John
          NA
          US
          +1.5556667777
          Doe
          3200 Northwest 67th Avenue
          
          Miami
          
          active
          tech@example.com
          33122
          
          FL
         
        
        
         
          active
          
          
          Los Angeles
          tech@example.com
          77788
          
          CA
          Company Name
          Jane Doe
          +1.5556667777
          US
          555 My Street
          Jane Doe
         
        
        
         
          +1.5556667777
          US
          NA
          John
          Doe
          3200 Northwest 67th Avenue
          tech@example.com
          Miami
          active
          
          
          33122
          
          FL
         
        
        
         
          33122
          active
          Miami
          
          
          tech@example.com
          FL
          
          John
          NA
          US
          +1.5556667777
          Doe
          3200 Northwest 67th Avenue
         
        
       
      
      
      
       
        
         
          ns1.systemdns.com
          
          1
         
        
        
         
          2
          
          ns2.systemdns.com
         
        
       
      
      2020-08-24 21:55:12
      2021-08-24 21:55:10
      NONE
      2020-08-24 21:55:10
      0
      1
      2021-08-24 21:55:10
```

Comment: Some indentation would be helpful in seeing the data structure

Comment: Could you also show what `echo $xml->asXML();` looks like?

Comment: @GetSet : I dont know how to do that here.

Comment: @JackFleeting: it returns a well formatted XML string without the extra stuff.

Comment: What do you mean by "the extra stuff"?

Comment: @JackFleeting : I will update with asXML(). Sorry for late answer I've been trying to figure out how to access this response. I think I've made progress. It seems that everything is stored in $xml->body->data_block->dt_assoc->item. I get offset errors when I try to access anything further than that. It's very confusing.

Comment: @JackFleeting : I have edited my post with $xml->asXML().

Comment: @JackFleeting: If it can help, I'm basically calling OpenSRS api. I'm making the all_info request example 1 (very last example) and they say this is the response that is supposed to be returned : https://domains.opensrs.guide/docs/get-domain which is not so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the very last example in the link you provide in your comment, something like the below - using xpath - should get you the admin info:

```
$admin = $xml->xpath('//item[@key="admin"]//item');
foreach($admin as $item) {
echo $item;    
}
```

Output:

```
US Admin Example Inc. +1.4165550123x1812 CA Suite 100 active Adams adams@example.com Santa Clara 90210 +1.4165550125 32 Oak Street Adler
```

Or to get server info for the server w/ id 2:

```
$server = $xml->xpath('//item[@key="nameserver_list"]//item[@key="2"]//dt_assoc//item');

foreach($server as $item) {
echo $item;    
}
```

Output:

```
24.22.23.28 3 patrick.example.com
```

etc.

Comment: Dude! You literally saved my life!

Comment: If I want to extract one value at a time without iteration, what would be the approach? This structure that you're presenting in your answer is new to me.